# $K(\zeta)/k(\zeta)$ is Galois (proof verification)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, solution-verification, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K/k$ be Galois and $\zeta$ be primitive $n$-th root of unity. I want to prove that $K(\zeta)/k(\zeta)$ is also Galois.

Proof: Recall that an extension is Galois iff it is a splitting field of separable polynomial. If $K$ is  the splitting field of $f(x) \in k[x]$  then $K(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of $\frac{f(x)}{ \operatorname{gcd}(f(x), \Phi_n(x))} \in k(\zeta)$ and that's it.

Am I right? If I am wrong, please, don't right your solution.

Comment: Well, when I taught abstract algebra, I made sure to point out that the compositum of two Galois extensions was Galois.

Comment: Yes you are right, but you could more easily simply say that $K(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of the same polynomial $f(x)\in k(\zeta)[x]$.

Comment: If $[K\colon k] = \infty$, it is clear that $K$ can't be expressed as a splitting field of a single separable polynomial $f$. In general, you need to use $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ instead.

Comment: I think it is rather simpler to show that $K(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $k(\zeta)$. The fact about compositums @Lubin brought up is very useful to know. Here I would use that to conclude that $K(\zeta)/k$ is Galois. This does imply that $K(\zeta)/k(\zeta)$ is also Galois, so it works.